# Set height of one div relative to another div in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set the height of a wrapper div ("wrap"), which contains all of the webpage content until the footer, in relation to another div ("custHeightFix"). I am using the following javascript to achieve this:

```
<!--JavaScript to set height of wrap div-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var elmnt = document.getElementById("custHeightFix");
var idmHeight = elmnt.offsetHeight;
var el = document.getElementById("wrap");
el.style.minHeight = idmHeight + 208 + "px";
console.log(el.style.minHeight);
```

This works perfectly fine. The problem is that I have a few elements with display:none to display:inline attribute change after hovering over them, and the JavaScript to calculate the "wrap" height brakes the layout (height shift) after hovering over these elements in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox and IE, which is a known issue.

This problem is due to the JavaScript, because when I remove it, the layout doesn't break. So what I would need to do is to set the height of "wrap" relative to "custHeightFix" in CSS. I know that there is the calc() function, but how do I address it to another div?

I know that similar questions have been posted before, but to my knowledge, none of these have been answered by a CSS solution.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. JS shouldn't be used to "style" anything. Try to refactor the layout to be possible to do what you want with CSS only.

Comment: Replace `display: none` with `visibility: hidden`

Comment: @Vladimir: Yes, I also figured out that JavaScript is not good for this excact purpose. But I did not find any way to set the height of the "wrap" div in CSS only, because when I set it to 100% height, it sets the 100% in relation to browser window size, but if the height is more than the browser window (in which case I have a scroll bar), the "wrap" div does not extent until the footer. For this purpose, I found that designers use JavaScript/jQuery to set a div's height.

Comment: You need to listen to the hover events and then execute your javascript again.

Comment: @Andreas: How would I do that? The above JavaScript is at the end of my script, just before the footer.

Comment: @Pablo: Thanks - this does prevent Chrome and Safari to break the layout. However, display:inline-block is not working properly anymore. Bu maybe this can be fixed.

Comment: See https://codetogo.io/how-to-listen-to-hover-event-in-javascript/
The problem is: You calculate the correct height only once, when the page loads initially. When the page content changes due to hover-effects, you need to update the height in order to adapt to the new content.

Comment: @Andreas. Thanks, I just tried it but it doesn't prevent Chrome to break the layout. Or I did implement it wrong...

Comment: Better to find a ready-made solution based on any CSS grid or framework.

Comment: Could you show us a functional snippet? This way we could help you in a more efficient way.

Comment: @Pablo: Thanks for getting back. I did follow Vladimirs suggestion and solved the problem by rewriting some of the div container and grid styles in CSS. By that, I do not need to set a height attribute anymore. It did involve quite some changes, but it works and is a clean solution without any javascript manipulation.